# Google map: Info-window

Tags: html, css

I mapped some objects and I created info-window using the following script:

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  info: '<h3 style="color:brown">' + ThName + '</h3>' + 
  '<img src = "' + photo1 + '" style="width:200px;height:150px; vertical-align:top;margin-right:.5em"/>' + 
  '<img src = "' + photo2 + '" style="width:200px;height:150px; vertical-align:top"/>' + 
  '<br/> ' + cap1 + ' ' + cap2
});
```

How can I put the captions cap1 under photo1 and cap2 under photo2?

My intial thought is to create a table with two columns and two rows but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google Maps API for my current project and used info-window for the same purpose. You can use it in a similar way if you like:

```
    var contentString = '<h3 style="color:brown">' + ThName + '</h3>' + 
                        '<figure>'+ '<img src = "' + photo1 + 
                        '"style="width:200px;height:150px; vertical- 
                        align:top;margin-right:.5em"/>' +
                        '<figcaption>'+ cap1 + '</figcaption>' +
                        '</figure>' + '<figure>'+ '<img src = "' + photo2 + 
                        '"style="width:200px;height:150px; vertical- 
                        align:top;"/>' +'<figcaption>'+ cap2 + 
                        '</figcaption>' + '</figure>';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    content: contentString
    });
```

For captions, I used figure and figcaption tags.